# How can I work around datatype size limitations?

Tags: objective-c, math, types, int, long-long

I have a game on the App Store and I'm getting reports that scores are in accurate and incorrectly reported. I'm using long long for just about all my math. Unfortunately, at about two billion, my math starts fizzling out because the scores are getting too large.

Is there a standard way to work around datatype size limits? How?

Comment: an unsigned long long is 64 bit, which can hold a max value of 18446744073709551615 , it's more likely your math goes bad because of doing arithmetic with an int or long somewhere which has a max value just above 2 billion.

Comment: You could also use NSDecimalNumber, if you wanted extreme precision.

Comment: `int` has a max of about 2 billion - you are probably using that somewhere by mistake *(it might be implicit eg. calling a built-in function that returns a `int` but you assign it to a `long long`)*

Answer (score 2):

An unsigned long long has a range of 0-18,446,744,073,709,551,615. You shouldn't be running into datatype limits if you're just doing integer math there.